# Code in function is not executing after returning from another class

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on sending email from my Flutter app using Google email.

I am able to signing to Gmail and the code executes up to a certain point and then skips the rest but an error is never thrown.

The function below is the function that calls the signIn and should send the email. However, the execution goes to the api.signIn() and when it returns the rest of the code in the function is skipped.

```
Future sendNewUserEmail() async {
    final api = GoogleAuthApi();
    final googleUser = await api.signIn(); <<< EXECUTION REACHES THIS LINE AND SKIPS THE REST
    const accessToken = '';

    final smtpServer = gmailSaslXoauth2('myemail@gmail.com', accessToken);
    final message = Message()
      ..from = const Address("myemail@gmail.com", "Deal Diligence")
      ..recipients = ['myemail@gmail.com']
      ..subject = "Welcome to Deal Diligence"
      ..text = "Welcome to Deal Diligence. Your password is NewPassord";

    try {
      await send(message, smtpServer);

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar((const SnackBar(
          content: CustomSnackBar(
              snackColor: Colors.red,
              snackMessage: 'Email was sent successfully'))));
    } on MailerException catch (e) {
      print(e);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar((SnackBar(
          content: CustomSnackBar(
              snackColor: Colors.red,
              snackMessage: 'Email did not sent, $e'))));
    }
  }
```

The class GoogleAuthApi is where the user is allowed to sign into their Google account if they are not.

```
class GoogleAuthApi {
  final _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Future<GoogleSignInAccount?> signIn() async {
    if (_googleSignIn.isSignedIn == true) {
      return _googleSignIn.currentUser;
    } else {
      return await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    }
  }
}
```

Why is the code in the function skipped?

Thanks

UPDATE:
I added a try/catch to the GoogleAuthApi class and the signIn is throwing an error:

code:"sign_in_failed"
details:null
hashCode:514467941
message:"com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: "
runtimeType:Type (PlatformException)
stacktrace:null

Comment: Are you sure the function is returning? I suspect the `api.signIn()` call never completes. Or you can wrap it in a try-catch block and see if it throws error

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I added the error thrown to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Message: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10

This issue occurs when the Google Sign-In for your app is not configured correctly. Please verify the following:

Ensure that your app package ID is correctly configured.
Double-check the SHA signature used in the Firebase /  Google Cloud Console for your app.
Correcting these configurations should resolve the ApiException: 10 issue you are encountering.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I updated the SHA with what I had in the Google Console. However, I am still getting the error message but now the execution get to the await send(message, smtpServer) line and throws this message: I/flutter ( 6100): Authentication Failed (code: 334), response:
I/flutter ( 6100): < eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==